# Trying to create an Array of Objects

Tags: android, arrays

I have an object I am trying to put in an array list:

```
class PlayerScores {

String playerName;
int played=0;
int win=0;
int draw=0;
int loss=0;
int points=0;


void playerNameSet(String name){
    playerName=name;
}
void played(){
    played=played+1;
}
void win(){
    win=win+1;
    points();
}
void draw(){
    draw=draw+1;
    points();
}
void loss(){
    loss=loss+1;
}

void points(){
    points = (win*3)+draw;
}

}
```

and basically, when the user has chose how many players there are I want to initialize an Array of these objects but I am getting errors. Here is the code for initializing the array and then assigning names to the players as well.

the array has been defined at the begining of my code and is public so I can use it in different activities: 
    "PlayerScores[] playersObjects;"

```
public PlayerScores[] makePlayerObjects() {
        playersObjects = new PlayerScores[players];
        for(int i = 0; i < players + 1; i++)
        {
            playersObjects[i].playerNameSet(name variable);
        }

    return playersObjects;
}
```

the error seems occur on the line where the name is being set but it is not to do with the name variable.

Any help would be massively appreciated, 
Thanks, Oli

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't actually set the objects in the Array. You first need to construct a `PlayerScores` object then you can access it.

```
public PlayerScores[] makePlayerObjects() {
        playersObjects = new PlayerScores[players];
        for(int i = 0; i < playersObjects.length; i++)
        {
            playersObjects[i] = new PlayerScores(); //make the object so we can access it
            playersObjects[i].playerNameSet(name variable);
        }

    return playersObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could also use a list.

```
 List<PlayerScores > myList = new ArrayList<PlayerScores>();
 for(int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
        myList.add(new PlayerScores().playerNameSet(thename));
 }
```

also note the `.size()` usage assuming players is a different array. if it is a `int` then forget the `.size()` part

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < players + 1; i++)
```

it will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, because array's index go from `0` to `size -1`

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not sure exactly what you mean, what part of that for loop do I need to change?

Comment: take out the +1, it should be for(int i = 0; i < playersObject.length)

Comment: @OliBlack the exit condition of the for loop. Since the array indexes go from 0 to array size - 1, the exit condition should be i < players. That is a very basically programming qustion